# Merge multiple rows with JSOB into one

Tags: postgresql

I have some rows that look like this:

```
"id","name","data","created_at"
110,"customerAdd","{\"age\": \"23\", \"name\": \"sally\", \"status\": \"valid\"}","2016-05-10 00:18:53.325752"
111,"customerUpdate","{\"age\": \"19\", \"name\": \"sally\"}","2016-05-10 00:18:53.331443"
112,"customerDelete","{\"name\": \"sally\", \"status\": \"deleted\"}","2016-05-10 00:18:53.338929"
```

Using a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE data->>'name' = 'sally';
```

I'm looking for a way to flatten / reduce / join all of these rows into one row.

Either in JSON, like this:

`{'age': 19, 'status': 'deleted', name: 'sally'}`

Or In actual columns, like this:

```
age, status, name
19, deleted, sally
```

The general idea is that I want to resolve each prop to the last value it was assigned, but I'd like this to happen deeply.

I'm just looking for any way to get started.

Comment: What do you mean by "flatten / reduce / join all of these rows into one row" ? You mean convert each JSON value into a record? Do you have a `customer` table with the fields age, deleted and sally already defined? You could use `jsonb_populate_record` for that if you do.

Comment: @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister If you see the json `data` columns in the first code block above. Those are the three rows I'm trying to merge into one, I just need the JSON merged, either in JSON or a normal table row. I don't have any table defined for this. Looking to generate it on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DISTINCT ON the keys and values from `jsonb_each_text`, ordered by `created_at desc`, and then recombine all values using `jsonb_object`:

```
with
  events(id,name,data,created_at) as (
    values (110,'customerAdd','{"age": "23", "name": "sally", "status": "valid"}'::jsonb,'2016-05-10 00:18:53.325752'::timestamp),
           (111,'customerUpdate','{"age": "19", "name": "sally"}','2016-05-10 00:18:53.331443'),
           (112,'customerDelete','{"name": "sally", "status": "deleted"}','2016-05-10 00:18:53.338929')
    ),
  flattened as (
    select distinct on (kv.key) *
    from events e
    join lateral jsonb_each_text(data) kv on true
    order by kv.key, e.created_at desc
    )

select jsonb_object(array(select key   from flattened order by key),
                    array(select value from flattened order by key))
```